# How do I create a javascript show/hide toggle for multiple elements that also changes text?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a show/hide toggle that is used multiple times per page. I believe the script I am using is working, but I would like it to also change the text of the link being clicked from "Read More" to "Read Less".

I have tried my best to sift through several many different posts on the website, but I just can't seem to figure out the changing text part. I've tried different variations of code, but none of them seem to do both of the tasks above.

```js
function toggleRead(id) {
    var toggle = document.getElementById(id);
    if (toggle.style.display == 'block') {
        toggle.style.display = 'none';
    } else toggle.style.display = 'block';
};
```

```html
<div style="display: none;" id="post-1">
  <p><strong>Hidden</strong> text inside this div container<p>
</div>

<p><a class="question" onclick="toggleRead('post-1')">Read More</a></p>

<div style="display: none;" id="post-2">
  <p><strong>Hidden</strong> text inside this div container<p>
</div>

<p><a class="question" onclick="toggleRead('post-2')">Read More</a></p>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could figure out how to change the text of the toggle link from "Read More" to "Read Less" and vice versa whenever it is clicked while maintaining the current functionality.

Comment: Simplest should be sent also this as parameter named say t inside function and then change t.innerText or t.innerHTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to reference the toggle links, in order to change its text as well.
I would write the whole thing in a different way, but to stick to your code, you can change it to also reference the "Read more" / "Read less" link:

```js
function toggleRead(id, triggeringLink) {
    var toggle = document.getElementById(id);
    if (toggle.style.display == 'block') {
     toggle.style.display = 'none';
                    triggeringLink.innerHTML = 'Read More';
    } else {
                    toggle.style.display = 'block';
                    triggeringLink.innerHTML = 'Read Less';
                }
   }
```

```html
   <div style="display: none;" id="post-1">
   <p><strong>Hidden</strong> text inside this div container</p>
   <p></p>
  </div>

  <p><a class="question" onclick="toggleRead('post-1', this)">Read More</a></p>

  <div style="display: none;" id="post-2">
   <p><strong>Hidden</strong> text inside this div container</p>
   <p></p>
  </div>

  <p><a class="question" onclick="toggleRead('post-2', this)">Read More</a></p>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the inner text also, then just add this code according to your conditions. 
add Id for each read more tag

```
document.getElementById('readmore').innerText='readless';
```

Comment: No such ID in his code and multiple same IDs will not work - get will return 1st only.